# Mysql isn't accepting remote connections

Tags: mysql

I've configured MySQL on my CentOS 6.5 64 bit server and configured it to accept remote connections from any IP.

When trying to connect through HeidiSQL it shows this error:

```
SQL Error (2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ip' (10060)
```

Here's my configuration:

/etc/my.conf

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
bind-address=SERVERIP
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

MySQL users:

```
mysql> SELECT User, Host, Password FROM mysql.user;
+--------+--------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| User   | Host               | Password                                  |
+--------+--------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| root   | localhost          | *|
| root   | nl.-----------.net | *|
| root   | 127.0.0.1          | *|
| radius | localhost          | *|
| radius | %                  | *|
| root   | %                  | *|
+--------+--------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

iptables:

```
[root@nl ~]# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Sat Aug  2 08:39:22 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2269:299675]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Aug  2 08:39:22 2014
```

SELinux config:

```
SELINUX=disabled
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these two values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

My host said no ports are blocked on their end. I disabled my firewall on my PC and it still gave me the same error. MySQL is running on the server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is most likely your problem:

```
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

**The rule ordering is wrong.** iptables rules are evaluated "top to bottom" and the first rule that matches (with very few exceptions) is the final one. You have a `REJECT` rule preceding the `ACCEPT` rule, so the REJECT rule takes precedence and the connection is refused.

Reverse the order of these two rules in your rule set and you will likely find that the error goes away.

*I'd also suggest* that you don't allow remote logins using the MySQL `root` account, as you appear to be doing based on the `mysql.user` table contents, *particularly* since you aren't doing anything to limit where on the Internet connections are allowed from. Instead, use a dedicated account and give it the permissions required to the appropriate databases, and consider tightening the security on the IP level as well.